# How to arrange web servers with Varnish?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, web-server, cache, varnish

I am wondering what it the best (most stable with the least memory footprint) arrangment for a busy php+mysql app?

```
request  > Varnish > Apache
requests > Varnish > Nginx > php5-fpm
requests > Varnish > Nginx  > Apache
requests > Nginx > Varnish  > Apache
something else
```

I appreciate your hints or references to relevant benchmarks. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure how anyone is reliably advising you without knowing ...

1. Is this going to be for 1 website, or multiple websites (reselling)?
2. What is the full exact server specification?
3. What are your targets for traffic (hits, pageviews, bandwidth commitment)?

The advice we give to our customers ...

#### If you need to re-sell hosting

Nginx > Apache > PHP-FPM

That keeps .htaccess support for your customers, security (chroot/multiple php.inis) from PHP-FPM and static file performance from Nginx.

#### If it is just for you

Pound > Varnish > Nginx > PHP-FPM

This gives you SSL unwrapping from Pound, static and dynamic (ESI) caching from Varnish, un-cached static content from Nginx and dynamic content from PHP-FPM

#### If you've got no real experience with Varnish

Apache > PHP-FPM

#### Our typical architecture is ...

If it helps, for web clusters, we typically use:

```
lvs (initial ssl load balancing)
    -> pound (ssl-unwrapping) 
    -> varnish (caching) 
    -> haproxy (load balancing) 
    -> nginx (static content) 
    -> php (dynamic content) 
    -> mysql (db)
```

The truth is that you can do a lot more damage than good with Varnish if you do not set it up properly (cached private sessions, unwanted cookie un-setting). The same applies to Nginx.

Have a read of this http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/mythbusting/why-shouldnt-i-use-nginx-for-magento/ and this [Building an SSL server farm](https://serverfault.com/questions/372607/building-an-ssl-server-farm)

**My final advice, consult a professional - its money well spent.**

Comment: Thanks mate. Really helpful answer. Just not sure why you choose Apache > PHP-FPM instead of nginx > PHP-FPM

Comment: It just depends on the use. Like I described above, different configs are more suitable for different situations. As a web host, Apache is far more suitable on our shared/Magento PaaS platform - and the performance differences are nil. On our Magento MicroCloud architecture, we used Nginx and PHP-FPM. It all comes down to suitability. Don't get caught up in the hype about which web server to use, read this http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/mythbusting/why-shouldnt-i-use-nginx-for-magento/